# Where can I see all objects I can make with the "new" operator in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, new-operator

Title basically. I want to know all the objects I can make with new in chrome - which are specific to Chrome/Chromium. For example:

```
new MessageChannel();

new TextEncoderStream();

new EyeDropper();
```

Is there a list of these methods somewhere?

Comment: There's probably not a consolidated list. Each class should be described in the documentation for that specific feature.

Comment: Found this : https://portswigger-labs.net/hackability/inspector/index.php?input=window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these are properties of `window`, you can try something like this:

```js
names = []

for (let k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)) {
  let v;
  try {
    v = window[k]
  } catch (e) {
  }
  if (k.match(/^[A-Z]/) && typeof v === 'function')
    names.push(k)
}

console.log(names.sort())
```

It doesn't tell whether these functions are really constructors though.